# How to embed external pics and incorporate header in ODS pdf -SAS

Tags: pdf, sas, ods

The idea is to create an output pdf file with just header and footer and embed a picture file. I have used ods pdf and specified ods overlay, region to get header , pagination and footer.proc print was used to embed picture and  a dummy dataset with only one variable was formatted to be blank.The problem is proc print creates a small dark line.Is it possible to control the color of the border of the table proc print produces? (i found proc print most helpful as it allows me to expand or compress the resolution of the picture)

Comment: Sure, modify your style template or use the style options in proc print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the style options in proc print to set your colour or create your own template.

```
proc print style(table)=[bordercolor=lightgrey];
```

Here's a link to a style that's based on Stephen Few's recommendations:
https://gist.github.com/statgeek/9845cc3d26e4c35e01a2